# How to write a "List(Of object) to a file in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, file, list, save

I have a class like this

```
Public Class alink
    Public url As String
    Public id As Integer
    Public linksto As New List(Of Integer)()
End Class
```

which is declared like this..

```
Public thelinklist As New List(Of alink)()
```

My question is how to go about writing and reading this list to file?

Im not sure what approach to use at all really!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you want the file to be used, if it's only for storing/loading the objects and need not to be human readable, you could use [serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx).

Comment: It only needs to be readable by the program.  I have looked at serialization but im sorry to say its going way over my head at the moment

Comment: read slowly, don't be too rush. it's simple once you get the concept, you don't even need to know how it's implemented.

Comment: I got it working :) Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!